# SAPUI5: Why i'm Not able to access data of ES4?

Tags: sapui5

**Why is this happening and how can i solve it?**

I have a problem getting the data from hanatrial.ondemand.com, i keep getting an authentication alert:
 [image]

heres my destination conf:
[image]

and heres my conf files:

**neo-app.json**

```
{
"welcomeFile": "index.html",
"routes": [{
    "path": "/resources",
    "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/resources"
    },
    "description": "SAPUI5 Resources"
}, {
    "path": "/test-resources",
    "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/test-resources"
    },
    "description": "SAPUI5 Test Resources"
}, {
    "path": "/destinations/ES4",
    "target": {
        "type": "destination",
        "name": "ES4"
    },
    "description": "ES4 Demo Service"
}
]
```

}

**menifest.json**

```
{
"_version": "1.3.0",

"sap.app": {
    "_version": "1.3.0",
    "id": "opensap.myapp",
    "type": "application",
    "title": "{{appTitle}}",
    "description": "{{appDescription}}",
    "applicationVersion": {
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },

    "dataSources": {
        "ES4": {
            "uri": "/destinations/ES4/sap/opu/odata/IWBEP/GWSAMPLE_BASIC/",
            "type": "OData",
            "settings": {
                "odataVersion": "2.0"
            }
        }
    },
    "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties"
},
"sap.ui": {
    "_version": "1.3.0",
    "technology": "UI5",
    "deviceTypes": {
        "desktop": true,
        "tablet": true,
        "phone": true
    },
    "supportedThemes": [
        "sap_bluecrystal"
    ]
},
"sap.ui5": {
    "_version": "1.2.0",
    "rootView": {
        "viewName": "opensap.myapp.view.App",
        "type": "XML",
        "id": "app"
    },
    "autoPrefixId": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "minUI5Version": "1.34",
        "libs": {
            "sap.ui.core": {
                "minVersion": "1.34.0"
            },
            "sap.m": {
                "minVersion": "1.34.0"
            },
            "sap.ui.layout": {
                "minVersion": "1.34.0"
            }
        }
    },
    "contentDensities": {
        "compact": true,
        "cozy": true
    },
    "models": {
        "": {
            "dataSource": "ES4"
        },
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "opensap.myapp.i18n.i18n"
            }
        },
        "address": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
            "uri": "model/Address.json"
        },
        "helloPanel": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
            "uri": "model/HelloPanel.json"
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Why is this happening and how can i solve it?**

this is the file that i'm supposed to retrive the data, but still no success:
https://sapes4.sapdevcenter.com/sap/opu/odata/IWBEP/GWSAMPLE_BASIC/$metadata

So how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

looks like the user or pw in the destination is wrong. use the same credentials in the destination configration as you would to access:
https://sapes4.sapdevcenter.com/sap/opu/odata/IWBEP/GWSAMPLE_BASIC/$metadata

Answer (score 0):

The dialog is for you to provide the system credentials of ES4. However, you can eliminate this by adding it in the destination of your SAP Cloud platform.

Nonetheless, the system ES4 is no more active and you can use ES5 for the sample Odata by simply creating a user.
https://sapes5.sapdevcenter.com/sap/opu/odata/iwbep/GWSAMPLE_BASIC/